# I cannot start jobhistoryserver in hadoop3.3

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

part of my shell script -- hdp.sh to start hadoop cluster :

[hdp.sh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuKBV.png)

but jobhistoryserver not started:

[process 'JobHistoryServer' should be there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfkKE.png)

and I found that jobhistoryserver could start alone util I excut : `$ hdp.sh start`

[process 'JobHistoryServer' just disappear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ck7O.png)

I don't know why.

---

[mapreduce-site.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my7H4.png)

[yarn-site.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ck28P.png)

Comment: I examined the script, I suppose you must be add sleep 10 after the yarn.sh line.

Answer (score 1):

The Job History Server is a Hadoop 1 process and doesn't need ran in Hadoop 2 or 3.

YARN's ResourceManager is the replacement. If the resource manager or node manager don't start, then you need to look at the actual process logs, not jps.

Regarding your script, Hortonworks "HDP" also doesn't exist anymore, so it seems you're referring to old documentation and you should be following the [latest installation processes](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html), which do not mention the history server.

Comment: That's my fault.  I set :       <name> mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address </name>
                                         <value> ater02:19888 </value>                                                                but start jobhistoryserver in another host : ater01 , I can access the page " http://ater02:19888/jobhistory/logs/logID" now .                                                                Your advice still helps, I added some changes accroding to the docmentation.  Thanks.

Comment: Huh? Still, JobHistory server is not needed. The history of all MapReduce jobs are available in YARN ResourceManager UI

Comment: Yes, I accept your idea now !

Comment: In order to accept this answer, please use the checkmark next to the post